# How do I completeley uninstall TVTime?

Tags: tvtime

Can anyone recommend how to **completely** un-install TVTime and reinstall it as I have a problem where it will not 'see' my TV Card at all.
It will not let me change input from 'default'  either.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04LTS

TVTime 1.0.2

TV Card PEAK 138508AGPK DVB-T Digital TV Hybrid PCI Card

I have tried uninstalling before but it leaves traces of itself so that when I reinstall it, it doesn’t ask where I am in relation to PAL/NTSC.
Also, how do I set up channels, I really only need ONE as I am using a Virgin Media TiVo box (UK)

Some TechSpec on the device

-multimedia description: Multimedia controller

```
            product: SAA7131/SAA7133/SAA7135 Video Broadcast Decoder
            vendor: Philips Semiconductors
            physical id: 7
            bus info: pci@0000:03:07.0
            version: d1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=saa7134 latency=64 maxlatency=255 mingnt=255
            resources: irq:21 memory:fbfef800-fbfeffff
```

More info;

```
[   30.791553] saa7130/34: v4l2 driver version 0, 2, 17 loaded
[   30.798887] saa7134 0000:03:07.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 21 (level, low) -> IRQ 21
[   30.798894] saa7133[0]: found at 0000:03:07.0, rev: 209, irq: 21, latency: 64, mmio: 0xfbfef800
[   30.798902] saa7134: <rant>
[   30.798902] saa7134:  Congratulations!  Your TV card vendor saved a few
[   30.798903] saa7134:  cents for a eeprom, thus your pci board has no
[   30.798904] saa7134:  subsystem ID and I can't identify it automatically
[   30.798905] saa7134: </rant>
[   30.798906] saa7134: I feel better now.  Ok, here are the good news:
[   30.798906] saa7134: You can use the card=<nr> insmod option to specify
[   30.798907] saa7134: which board do you have.  The list:
[   30.798910] saa7134:   card=0 -> UNKNOWN/GENERIC                         
[   30.798916] saa7134:   card=1 -> Proteus Pro [philips reference design]   1131:2001 1131:2001
[   30.798920] saa7134:   card=2 -> LifeView FlyVIDEO3000                    5168:0138 4e42:0138
[   30.798924] saa7134:   card=3 -> LifeView/Typhoon FlyVIDEO2000            5168:0138 4e42:0138
[   30.798927] saa7134:   card=4 -> EMPRESS                                  1131:6752
[   30.798930] saa7134:   card=5 -> SKNet Monster TV                         1131:4e85
[   30.798933] saa7134:   card=6 -> Tevion MD 9717                          
[   30.798936] saa7134:   card=7 -> KNC One TV-Station RDS / Typhoon TV Tune 1131:fe01 1894:fe01
[   30.798940] saa7134:   card=8 -> Terratec Cinergy 400 TV                  153b:1142
[   30.798943] saa7134:   card=9 -> Medion 5044                             
[   30.798945] saa7134:   card=10 -> Kworld/KuroutoShikou SAA7130-TVPCI      
[   30.798948] saa7134:   card=11 -> Terratec Cinergy 600 TV                  153b:1143
[   30.798951] saa7134:   card=12 -> Medion 7134                              16be:0003 16be:5000
[   30.798955] saa7134:   card=13 -> Typhoon TV+Radio 90031                  
[   30.798957] saa7134:   card=14 -> ELSA EX-VISION 300TV                     1048:226b
[   30.798960] saa7134:   card=15 -> ELSA EX-VISION 500TV                     1048:226a
[   30.798963] saa7134:   card=16 -> ASUS TV-FM 7134                          1043:4842 1043:4830 1043:4840
[   30.798967] saa7134:   card=17 -> AOPEN VA1000 POWER                       1131:7133
[   30.798970] saa7134:   card=18 -> BMK MPEX No Tuner                       
[   30.798973] saa7134:   card=19 -> Compro VideoMate TV                      185b:c100
[   30.798976] saa7134:   card=20 -> Matrox CronosPlus                        102b:48d0
[   30.798979] saa7134:   card=21 -> 10MOONS PCI TV CAPTURE CARD              1131:2001
[   30.798982] saa7134:   card=22 -> AverMedia M156 / Medion 2819             1461:a70b
[   30.798985] saa7134:   card=23 -> BMK MPEX Tuner                          
[   30.798987] saa7134:   card=24 -> KNC One TV-Station DVR                   1894:a006
[   30.798990] saa7134:   card=25 -> ASUS TV-FM 7133                          1043:4843
[   30.798993] saa7134:   card=26 -> Pinnacle PCTV Stereo (saa7134)           11bd:002b
[   30.798997] saa7134:   card=27 -> Manli MuchTV M-TV002                    
[   30.798999] saa7134:   card=28 -> Manli MuchTV M-TV001                    
[   30.799002] saa7134:   card=29 -> Nagase Sangyo TransGear 3000TV           1461:050c
[   30.799005] saa7134:   card=30 -> Elitegroup ECS TVP3XP FM1216 Tuner Card( 1019:4cb4
[   30.799008] saa7134:   card=31 -> Elitegroup ECS TVP3XP FM1236 Tuner Card  1019:4cb5
[   30.799011] saa7134:   card=32 -> AVACS SmartTV                           
[   30.799013] saa7134:   card=33 -> AVerMedia DVD EZMaker                    1461:10ff
[   30.799016] saa7134:   card=34 -> Noval Prime TV 7133                     
[   30.799019] saa7134:   card=35 -> AverMedia AverTV Studio 305              1461:2115
[   30.799022] saa7134:   card=36 -> UPMOST PURPLE TV                         12ab:0800
[   30.799025] saa7134:   card=37 -> Items MuchTV Plus / IT-005              
[   30.799028] saa7134:   card=38 -> Terratec Cinergy 200 TV                  153b:1152
[   30.799031] saa7134:   card=39 -> LifeView FlyTV Platinum Mini             5168:0212 4e42:0212 5169:1502
[   30.799035] saa7134:   card=40 -> Compro VideoMate TV PVR/FM               185b:c100
[   30.799038] saa7134:   card=41 -> Compro VideoMate TV Gold+                185b:c100
[   30.799041] saa7134:   card=42 -> Sabrent SBT-TVFM (saa7130)              
[   30.799043] saa7134:   card=43 -> :Zolid Xpert TV7134                     
[   30.799046] saa7134:   card=44 -> Empire PCI TV-Radio LE                  
[   30.799048] saa7134:   card=45 -> Avermedia AVerTV Studio 307              1461:9715
[   30.799051] saa7134:   card=46 -> AVerMedia Cardbus TV/Radio (E500)        1461:d6ee
[   30.799054] saa7134:   card=47 -> Terratec Cinergy 400 mobile              153b:1162
[   30.799057] saa7134:   card=48 -> Terratec Cinergy 600 TV MK3              153b:1158
[   30.799060] saa7134:   card=49 -> Compro VideoMate Gold+ Pal               185b:c200
[   30.799063] saa7134:   card=50 -> Pinnacle PCTV 300i DVB-T + PAL           11bd:002d
[   30.799067] saa7134:   card=51 -> ProVideo PV952                           1540:9524
[   30.799070] saa7134:   card=52 -> AverMedia AverTV/305                     1461:2108
[   30.799073] saa7134:   card=53 -> ASUS TV-FM 7135                          1043:4845
[   30.799076] saa7134:   card=54 -> LifeView FlyTV Platinum FM / Gold        5168:0214 5168:5214 1489:0214 5168:0304
[   30.799080] saa7134:   card=55 -> LifeView FlyDVB-T DUO / MSI TV@nywhere D 5168:0306 4e42:0306
[   30.799084] saa7134:   card=56 -> Avermedia AVerTV 307                     1461:a70a
[   30.799087] saa7134:   card=57 -> Avermedia AVerTV GO 007 FM               1461:f31f
[   30.799090] saa7134:   card=58 -> ADS Tech Instant TV (saa7135)            1421:0350 1421:0351 1421:0370 1421:1370
[   30.799095] saa7134:   card=59 -> Kworld/Tevion V-Stream Xpert TV PVR7134 
[   30.799097] saa7134:   card=60 -> LifeView/Typhoon/Genius FlyDVB-T Duo Car 5168:0502 4e42:0502 1489:0502
[   30.799101] saa7134:   card=61 -> Philips TOUGH DVB-T reference design     1131:2004
[   30.799104] saa7134:   card=62 -> Compro VideoMate TV Gold+II             
[   30.799107] saa7134:   card=63 -> Kworld Xpert TV PVR7134                 
[   30.799109] saa7134:   card=64 -> FlyTV mini Asus Digimatrix               1043:0210
[   30.799112] saa7134:   card=65 -> V-Stream Studio TV Terminator           
[   30.799115] saa7134:   card=66 -> Yuan TUN-900 (saa7135)                  
[   30.799117] saa7134:   card=67 -> Beholder BeholdTV 409 FM                 0000:4091
[   30.799120] saa7134:   card=68 -> GoTView 7135 PCI                         5456:7135
[   30.799124] saa7134:   card=69 -> Philips EUROPA V3 reference design       1131:2004
[   30.799127] saa7134:   card=70 -> Compro Videomate DVB-T300                185b:c900
[   30.799130] saa7134:   card=71 -> Compro Videomate DVB-T200                185b:c901
[   30.799133] saa7134:   card=72 -> RTD Embedded Technologies VFG7350        1435:7350
[   30.799136] saa7134:   card=73 -> RTD Embedded Technologies VFG7330        1435:7330
[   30.799139] saa7134:   card=74 -> LifeView FlyTV Platinum Mini2            14c0:1212
[   30.799142] saa7134:   card=75 -> AVerMedia AVerTVHD MCE A180              1461:1044
[   30.799145] saa7134:   card=76 -> SKNet MonsterTV Mobile                   1131:4ee9
[   30.799148] saa7134:   card=77 -> Pinnacle PCTV 40i/50i/110i (saa7133)     11bd:002e
[   30.799151] saa7134:   card=78 -> ASUSTeK P7131 Dual                       1043:4862
[   30.799154] saa7134:   card=79 -> Sedna/MuchTV PC TV Cardbus TV/Radio (ITO
[   30.799157] saa7134:   card=80 -> ASUS Digimatrix TV                       1043:0210
[   30.799160] saa7134:   card=81 -> Philips Tiger reference design           1131:2018
[   30.799163] saa7134:   card=82 -> MSI TV@Anywhere plus                     1462:6231 1462:8624
[   30.799166] saa7134:   card=83 -> Terratec Cinergy 250 PCI TV              153b:1160
[   30.799169] saa7134:   card=84 -> LifeView FlyDVB Trio                     5168:0319
[   30.799172] saa7134:   card=85 -> AverTV DVB-T 777                         1461:2c05 1461:2c05
[   30.799176] saa7134:   card=86 -> LifeView FlyDVB-T / Genius VideoWonder D 5168:0301 1489:0301
[   30.799180] saa7134:   card=87 -> ADS Instant TV Duo Cardbus PTV331        0331:1421
[   30.799183] saa7134:   card=88 -> Tevion/KWorld DVB-T 220RF                17de:7201
[   30.799186] saa7134:   card=89 -> ELSA EX-VISION 700TV                     1048:226c
[   30.799189] saa7134:   card=90 -> Kworld ATSC110/115                       17de:7350 17de:7352
[   30.799192] saa7134:   card=91 -> AVerMedia A169 B                         1461:7360
[   30.799195] saa7134:   card=92 -> AVerMedia A169 B1                        1461:6360
[   30.799199] saa7134:   card=93 -> Medion 7134 Bridge #2                    16be:0005
[   30.799202] saa7134:   card=94 -> LifeView FlyDVB-T Hybrid Cardbus/MSI TV  5168:3306 5168:3502 5168:3307 4e42:3502
[   30.799206] saa7134:   card=95 -> LifeView FlyVIDEO3000 (NTSC)             5169:0138
[   30.799209] saa7134:   card=96 -> Medion Md8800 Quadro                     16be:0007 16be:0008 16be:000d
[   30.799213] saa7134:   card=97 -> LifeView FlyDVB-S /Acorp TV134DS         5168:0300 4e42:0300
[   30.799217] saa7134:   card=98 -> Proteus Pro 2309                         0919:2003
[   30.799220] saa7134:   card=99 -> AVerMedia TV Hybrid A16AR                1461:2c00
[   30.799223] saa7134:   card=100 -> Asus Europa2 OEM                         1043:4860
[   30.799226] saa7134:   card=101 -> Pinnacle PCTV 310i                       11bd:002f
[   30.799229] saa7134:   card=102 -> Avermedia AVerTV Studio 507              1461:9715
[   30.799232] saa7134:   card=103 -> Compro Videomate DVB-T200A              
[   30.799235] saa7134:   card=104 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1110 DVB-T/Hybrid     0070:6700 0070:6701 0070:6702 0070:6703 0070:6704 0070:6705
[   30.799240] saa7134:   card=105 -> Terratec Cinergy HT PCMCIA               153b:1172
[   30.799243] saa7134:   card=106 -> Encore ENLTV                             1131:2342 1131:2341 3016:2344
[   30.799247] saa7134:   card=107 -> Encore ENLTV-FM                          1131:230f
[   30.799250] saa7134:   card=108 -> Terratec Cinergy HT PCI                  153b:1175
[   30.799254] saa7134:   card=109 -> Philips Tiger - S Reference design      
[   30.799256] saa7134:   card=110 -> Avermedia M102                           1461:f31e
[   30.799259] saa7134:   card=111 -> ASUS P7131 4871                          1043:4871
[   30.799262] saa7134:   card=112 -> ASUSTeK P7131 Hybrid                     1043:4876
[   30.799265] saa7134:   card=113 -> Elitegroup ECS TVP3XP FM1246 Tuner Card  1019:4cb6
[   30.799268] saa7134:   card=114 -> KWorld DVB-T 210                         17de:7250
[   30.799271] saa7134:   card=115 -> Sabrent PCMCIA TV-PCB05                  0919:2003
[   30.799274] saa7134:   card=116 -> 10MOONS TM300 TV Card                    1131:2304
[   30.799277] saa7134:   card=117 -> Avermedia Super 007                      1461:f01d
[   30.799280] saa7134:   card=118 -> Beholder BeholdTV 401                    0000:4016
[   30.799284] saa7134:   card=119 -> Beholder BeholdTV 403                    0000:4036
[   30.799287] saa7134:   card=120 -> Beholder BeholdTV 403 FM                 0000:4037
[   30.799290] saa7134:   card=121 -> Beholder BeholdTV 405                    0000:4050
[   30.799293] saa7134:   card=122 -> Beholder BeholdTV 405 FM                 0000:4051
[   30.799296] saa7134:   card=123 -> Beholder BeholdTV 407                    0000:4070
[   30.799299] saa7134:   card=124 -> Beholder BeholdTV 407 FM                 0000:4071
[   30.799302] saa7134:   card=125 -> Beholder BeholdTV 409                    0000:4090
[   30.799305] saa7134:   card=126 -> Beholder BeholdTV 505 FM                 5ace:5050
[   30.799308] saa7134:   card=127 -> Beholder BeholdTV 507 FM / BeholdTV 509  5ace:5070 5ace:5090
[   30.799312] saa7134:   card=128 -> Beholder BeholdTV Columbus TV/FM         0000:5201
[   30.799315] saa7134:   card=129 -> Beholder BeholdTV 607 FM                 5ace:6070
[   30.799318] saa7134:   card=130 -> Beholder BeholdTV M6                     5ace:6190
[   30.799321] saa7134:   card=131 -> Twinhan Hybrid DTV-DVB 3056 PCI          1822:0022
[   30.799324] saa7134:   card=132 -> Genius TVGO AM11MCE                     
[   30.799327] saa7134:   card=133 -> NXP Snake DVB-S reference design        
[   30.799329] saa7134:   card=134 -> Medion/Creatix CTX953 Hybrid             16be:0010
[   30.799332] saa7134:   card=135 -> MSI TV@nywhere A/D v1.1                  1462:8625
[   30.799335] saa7134:   card=136 -> AVerMedia Cardbus TV/Radio (E506R)       1461:f436
[   30.799338] saa7134:   card=137 -> AVerMedia Hybrid TV/Radio (A16D)         1461:f936
[   30.799341] saa7134:   card=138 -> Avermedia M115                           1461:a836
[   30.799344] saa7134:   card=139 -> Compro VideoMate T750                    185b:c900
[   30.799347] saa7134:   card=140 -> Avermedia DVB-S Pro A700                 1461:a7a1
[   30.799350] saa7134:   card=141 -> Avermedia DVB-S Hybrid+FM A700           1461:a7a2
[   30.799353] saa7134:   card=142 -> Beholder BeholdTV H6                     5ace:6290
[   30.799356] saa7134:   card=143 -> Beholder BeholdTV M63                    5ace:6191
[   30.799360] saa7134:   card=144 -> Beholder BeholdTV M6 Extra               5ace:6193
[   30.799363] saa7134:   card=145 -> AVerMedia MiniPCI DVB-T Hybrid M103      1461:f636 1461:f736
[   30.799366] saa7134:   card=146 -> ASUSTeK P7131 Analog                    
[   30.799369] saa7134:   card=147 -> Asus Tiger 3in1                          1043:4878
[   30.799372] saa7134:   card=148 -> Encore ENLTV-FM v5.3                     1a7f:2008
[   30.799375] saa7134:   card=149 -> Avermedia PCI pure analog (M135A)        1461:f11d
[   30.799378] saa7134:   card=150 -> Zogis Real Angel 220                    
[   30.799380] saa7134:   card=151 -> ADS Tech Instant HDTV                    1421:0380
[   30.799383] saa7134:   card=152 -> Asus Tiger Rev:1.00                      1043:4857
[   30.799387] saa7134:   card=153 -> Kworld Plus TV Analog Lite PCI           17de:7128
[   30.799390] saa7134:   card=154 -> Avermedia AVerTV GO 007 FM Plus          1461:f31d
[   30.799393] saa7134:   card=155 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1150 ATSC/QAM-Hybrid  0070:6706 0070:6708
[   30.799396] saa7134:   card=156 -> Hauppauge WinTV-HVR1120 DVB-T/Hybrid     0070:6707 0070:6709 0070:670a
[   30.799400] saa7134:   card=157 -> Avermedia AVerTV Studio 507UA            1461:a11b
[   30.799403] saa7134:   card=158 -> AVerMedia Cardbus TV/Radio (E501R)       1461:b7e9
[   30.799407] saa7134:   card=159 -> Beholder BeholdTV 505 RDS                0000:505b
[   30.799410] saa7134:   card=160 -> Beholder BeholdTV 507 RDS                0000:5071
[   30.799413] saa7134:   card=161 -> Beholder BeholdTV 507 RDS                0000:507b
[   30.799416] saa7134:   card=162 -> Beholder BeholdTV 607 FM                 5ace:6071
[   30.799419] saa7134:   card=163 -> Beholder BeholdTV 609 FM                 5ace:6090
[   30.799422] saa7134:   card=164 -> Beholder BeholdTV 609 FM                 5ace:6091
[   30.799425] saa7134:   card=165 -> Beholder BeholdTV 607 RDS                5ace:6072
[   30.799428] saa7134:   card=166 -> Beholder BeholdTV 607 RDS                5ace:6073
[   30.799431] saa7134:   card=167 -> Beholder BeholdTV 609 RDS                5ace:6092
[   30.799434] saa7134:   card=168 -> Beholder BeholdTV 609 RDS                5ace:6093
[   30.799437] saa7134:   card=169 -> Compro VideoMate S350/S300               185b:c900
[   30.799440] saa7134:   card=170 -> AverMedia AverTV Studio 505              1461:a115
[   30.799443] saa7134:   card=171 -> Beholder BeholdTV X7                     5ace:7595
[   30.799446] saa7134:   card=172 -> RoverMedia TV Link Pro FM                19d1:0138
[   30.799449] saa7134:   card=173 -> Zolid Hybrid TV Tuner PCI                1131:2004
[   30.799452] saa7134:   card=174 -> Asus Europa Hybrid OEM                   1043:4847
[   30.799455] saa7134:   card=175 -> Leadtek Winfast DTV1000S                 107d:6655
[   30.799458] saa7134:   card=176 -> Beholder BeholdTV 505 RDS                0000:5051
[   30.799461] saa7134:   card=177 -> Hawell HW-404M7                         
[   30.799464] saa7134:   card=178 -> Beholder BeholdTV H7                     5ace:7190
[   30.799467] saa7134:   card=179 -> Beholder BeholdTV A7                     5ace:7090
[   30.799470] saa7134:   card=180 -> Avermedia PCI M733A                      1461:4155 1461:4255
[   30.799474] saa7134:   card=181 -> TechoTrend TT-budget T-3000              13c2:2804
[   30.799477] saa7134:   card=182 -> Kworld PCI SBTVD/ISDB-T Full-Seg Hybrid  17de:b136
[   30.799480] saa7134:   card=183 -> Compro VideoMate Vista M1F               185b:c900
[   30.799483] saa7134:   card=184 -> Encore ENLTV-FM 3                        1a7f:2108
[   30.799486] saa7134:   card=185 -> MagicPro ProHDTV Pro2 DMB-TH/Hybrid      17de:d136
[   30.799489] saa7134:   card=186 -> Beholder BeholdTV 501                    5ace:5010
[   30.799492] saa7134:   card=187 -> Beholder BeholdTV 503 FM                 5ace:5030
[   30.799496] saa7133[0]: subsystem: 17de:7253, board: UNKNOWN/GENERIC [card=0,autodetected]
[   30.799520] saa7133[0]: board init: gpio is 100
[   30.880272] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   30.882137] device-mapper: multipath: version 1.3.0 loaded
[   30.952040] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 00: de 17 53 72 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952049] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 10: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952056] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952063] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952069] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 40: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952076] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952082] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952088] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952095] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952101] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom 90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952108] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952114] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952120] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952127] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952133] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.952140] saa7133[0]: i2c eeprom f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[   30.954319] saa7133[0]: registered device video0 [v4l2]
[   30.954380] saa7133[0]: registered device vbi0
[   30.984113] saa7134 ALSA driver for DMA sound loaded
[   30.984147] saa7133[0]/alsa: saa7133[0] at 0xfbfef800 irq 21 registered as card -2
```

Answer (score 0):

(sudo) apt-get purge [package_name]

This command completely removes a package and the associated configuration files. Configuration files residing in ~ are not usually affected by this command.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto